# Can DataMapper `Decimal` properties to automatically round to the correct scale?

Tags: ruby, decimal, datamapper, rounding, datamapper-1.2

Suppose I have the following DataMapper model:

```
class Payment
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :amount, Decimal, precision: 8, scale: 2
end
```

Then I do the following:

```
p = Payment.new(:amount => 12.3245)
```

This payment will be invalid (at least with DataMapper 1.2), saying that `Amount must be a number`.

Of course, amount **is** a number (**shakes fist**); it just has more decimal places than the property will accept. If I do `p.amount = p.amount.round(2)`, the payment will be valid.

I **could** write a setter to take away this annoyance:

```
def amount=(val)
  @amount = val.round(2)
end
```

...but then I have the annoyance of writing a bunch of identical setters on different models.

I would much prefer to handle this with the same, sensible rule for all `Decimal` properties, system-wide. Namely, **since you know your own scale, round to that scale before saving**.

Is this something that can be handled with a configuration option, or maybe an initializer?

Comment: With what database have you had this issue? It seems like it works for me on sqlite.

Comment: @Flexoid - MySQL 5.1.54 and DataMapper 1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could monkey patch DataMapper's `Decimal` class ([original](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core/blob/v1.2.0/lib/dm-core/property/decimal.rb) at `dm-core-1.2.0/lib/dm-core/property/decimal.rb`):

```
module DataMapper
  class Property
    class Decimal
      alias :original_typecast_to_primitive :typecast_to_primitive
      def typecast_to_primitive(value)
        typecasted = original_typecast_to_primitive(value)
        typecasted.round(@scale) if typecasted.respond_to?(:round)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

or you could define you own property type `NiceDecimal` with the new behavior.

Comment: Nice suggestion. Although I wouldn't want to always round to 2; I'd want to always round to whatever scale that property specified.

Comment: Okay, then do `typecast_to_numeric(value.round(@scale), :to_d)`.

Comment: Hope you don't mind my modification. The improvements I made are: 1) I'm only rounding values that `respond_to?` round (eg, not blank strings) and 2) if the original method gets updated, this uses the updated version. (I couldn't use `super` because we're not subclassing, so `alias` serves the same purpose.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered writing your own DataMapper data types for each of your scale categories? That way, there's no monkey-patching and you can specify as many cases as you want without littering any existing class with `if` / `switch` statements. DataMapper has a mechanism for this, see a list of custom data types in the "Available Types" section of [the properties docs](http://datamapper.org/docs/properties.html).